# Caddy server, X-Forwarded-For and spoofed value

Tags: python, flask, caddy

Using Caddy server and a `reverse_proxy` server like the following :

```
my.domain.com {
    reverse_proxy * unix//path/to/socket
}
```

I can easily access my request headers doing the following in Python/Flask:

```
request.headers.get('X-Forwarded-For')
```

Which returns a list of values, based on the request. The [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/X-Forwarded-For) stipulate that the first value is the client IP, which I rely on, but I recently discovered that this value can be spoofed, like the following:

```
# Using Python requests
requests.get('https://my.domain.com', headers={'X-Forwarded-For': 'www.google.com'})
```

In that case, the header value is :

`X-Forwarded-For: www.google.com, xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx`
(xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx being, in that case, my valid IP).

My question: How can I retrieve, with certainty, the IP of the client, excluding any spoofing?

**Details**:

I tested for the following headers in Flask, which are all set to None using my above Caddy configuration:

```
Remote Addr: 0.0.0.0
X-Forwarded-For: www.google.com, xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
Remote-Addr: None
Client-Ip: None
X-Forwarded: None
X-Cluster-Client-Ip: None
Forwarded-For: None
Forwarded: None
```

Comment: I don't understand the problem, so caddy append to the actual `X-Forwarded-For` instead of overriding it. You can just take the last one or configure caddy to override this HEADER. 

I am not related to the downvote

Comment: The misconception is that Caddy does not append the actual X-Forwarded-For, it *prepends* it! That's what caused the issue here, but pushed me to wonder if the whole header might be tampered with, on how to rely on this header with certainty.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As stated on [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X-Forwarded-For#Format), the general format of the `X-Forwarded-For` is:

```
X-Forwarded-For: client, proxy1, proxy2
```

where the value is a comma+space separated list of IP addresses, the left-most being the original client, and each successive proxy that passed the request adding the IP address where it received the request from.

In this example, the request passed through proxy1, proxy2, and then **caddy** (not shown in the header). **caddy** appears as remote address of the request.

Since it is easy to forge an X-Forwarded-For field the given information should be used with care. The right-most IP address is always the IP address that connects to the last proxy, which means it is the most reliable source of information.

In short: pick the last value !